# Sending request onunload

Tags: jquery

I have read multiple questions on this subject in here but I still have some doubts on it.

I firstly tried using the Navigator.sendBeacon() which it works perfectly but I need to support all browser, so it can't be used.

The solution that I came up with was:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/express/check", false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.send();
            xhr.abort();
        })
```

I have tried changing the link to one that doesn't exist and disconnecting the internet while doing it and it worked fine on Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer since the page closed properly.

My concern is: will this work seamlessly on all types of Browser, or is there potential problems (i.e. the page waiting for the request and therefore not closing) even with aborting after a send()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try `$(window).on('beforeunload'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) like following which is almost compatible in every browser. See here [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) . Scroll down to Browser compatibility

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/express/check", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send();
    xhr.abort();
 });
```